# How to store and get two values in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

This is process_upcategory.php
I want to update the category name or the category id with another category name/id by its category id or by its category name.
I'm new to php

```
<?php
     require('includes/config.php');
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $msg=array();
        if(empty($_POST['cat']))
        {
            $msg[]="Please full fill all requirement";
        }

        if(!empty($msg))
        {
            echo '<b>Error:-</b><br>';

            foreach($msg as $k)
            {
                echo '<li>'.$k;
            }
        }
        else
        {


            $cat_nm=$_POST['cat[0]'];
            $cat_id=$_POST['cat[1]'];

            $query= "UPDATE `category` SET cat_nm='$cat_nm' WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'";

            mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("can't Execute...");

            mysql_close($link);
            header("location:category.php");
        }


    }

    else
    {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

Now this is category.php, just a snippet of code. Not whole code

```
<form action='process_upcategory.php' method='POST'>

                        <b style="color:darkgreen">UPDATE CATEGORY </b> <br>    
                        <b style="color:darkgreen">Old Category</b>             
                            <br>
                                <select name="cat[]" multiple>
                                    <?php

                                            $query="select * from category ";

                                            $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                                            {
                                                echo "<option>".$row['cat_nm'];
                                                echo "<option>".$row['cat_id'];
                                            }


                                    ?>

                                </select>
                        <br>
                        <b style="color:darkgreen">New Category</b><br>
                        <input type='text' name='cat[0]'></input><br>
                        <input type='text' name='cat[1]'></input>

                            <input type='submit' value='  UPDATE  '>


</form>
```

I want to update the category name with another category name by its category id or by its category name. I get undefined index cat[0] and cat[1]

Comment: check for errors then tell us what those were

Comment: not to mention mixing different mysql apis and the api to connect with, is unknown.

Comment: undefined index cat[0] and cat[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you end an input name with [] it wil be converted to an array by php. The correct way to get the values in this case would be something like this:

```
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$cat_nm=$cat[0];
$cat_id=$cat[1];
```

Comment: Putting the cat_id in a separate `<option>` is just wrong and complicates things.  Name and ID should be passed in a single `<option>`.   Name and ID should both be passed with the same cat[] index.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the two routines into one script.

I added 'sub' to the form to distinguish from when the form was submitted or not.

I used list() in the query result loop.
Used `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)` rather than `mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)`

used foreach() to loop through the $_POST['cat']

Added 'value' to the `<option value="">` to hold the id

Eliminated the switching from HTML mode to PHP mode by using HEREDOC.

```
<?php
if (intval($_POST['sub']) == 1){
  $newcat = $_POST['new'];
  foreach($_POST['cat'] as $key=>$value){
    if(strlen($newcat[$key]) > 0){
      mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `category` SET `cat_nm`='$newcat[$key]' WHERE `cat_id`='$value'");
    }
  }
}
echo <<<EOT
<html><head><style>h4,h3{color:darkgreen;margin:.2em;}</style></head><body>
<form action="#" method='POST'>
  <h3>UPDATE CATEGORY</h3>    
  <h4>Old Category</h3> 
  <select name="cat[]" multiple>
EOT;

$sql="SELECT `cat_nm`, `cat_id` FROM `category` ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while(list($cat_nm,$cat_id) = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo "  <option value=\"$cat_id\">$cat_nm</option>\n";
}
echo <<<EOT
  </select>
  <h3>New Category</h3>
  <input type="text" name="new[0]" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="new[1]" /><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="  UPDATE  />
</form> 
</body></html>
EOT;
?>
```